# How to detect nested mapping value existing

Tags: solidity

I have mapping of mappings `mapping(address => mapping(bytes32 => address))`. How to detect that second-level mapping exists?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, not without another mapping that keeps track of existance like this: `mapping(address => bool) mappingExists`

That's because in Ethereum, every entry of a mapping is defined.

Answer (score 0):

In Ethereum, when you define a mapping, all values are defined, with value 0.

So, depending on what you store on the mapping, you can use something like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Test {

    mapping(address => mapping(bytes32 => address)) testMapping;

    function didItChangeIt() public returns(bool) {
        address _address = msg.sender;
        bytes32 _bytes32 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_address));
        if (testMapping[_address][_bytes32] == 0) {
            testMapping[_address][_bytes32] = _address;
            return (true);
        }
        return (false);
    }
}
```

If you put this code on Remix, you'll notice that it only returns true the first time you call the function didItChangeIt(), which means the test works.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you know the key of the parent mapping and you want to know if addresses were registered in the second mapping.
This is not possible because mappings are stored over the entire 256-bit addressable storage.

For example let's consider this one-level mapping:

```
mapping(bytes32 => address) example;
```

To access `example[key]` the contract will calculate `sha3(key+pos)` and read memory at that address.

`key` is a bytes32 variable and `pos` is the index of `example` in the contract storage.

The issue is the same for a two-level mapping.

More informations are provided in this blog post: https://medium.com/aigang-network/how-to-read-ethereum-contract-storage-44252c8af925